# How to adjust TrackballControls pan speed based on model size?

Tags: three.js

I'm using STLLoader to load a 3d model in an orthographic camera.  I'm using trackball controls to move the object.  When panning, the speed varies based on the 3d model size.  For example, on small 3d models, a small mouse movement will pan the model a distance of 3-4x or more on the screen, but on larger models a large mouse movement will pan the model hardly any distance at all on the screen.  I would like to pan the model, regardless of size, at a 1:1 mouse movement ration. FYI i'm also resizing the camera frustums based on the model boundingBox.

Comment: (1) You should be using `OrthographicTrackballControls` if you have an orthographic camera. (2) In any event, update to the current three.js version and try `OrbitControls`, instead, and see if it has the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: OrbitControls has everything i'm looking for except for the camera up enforcement (I need the camera to be able to rotate upside down as in trackball controls).  I should be using the current version (just downloaded it).  How can you see what version you have?

Comment: (1) The revision number is posted in the console. (2) You will have to study the `OrbitControls` source code and figure out how to modify the other controls.